# Function in scheme that takes list as an input and outputs a function

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to create an function which takes list  as an input and outputs a function . I am confused with the recursion calls that has to be made to traverse through the list.

```
(define S ( buildfunc '(1 0 -2 -3 4) ) )
```

Eg:
a function would be produced that takes as input an integer and

- adds 1 to it
- squares the result
- multiplies the square by 2,
- multiplies that last result by 3,
- and adds 4

If (S 4) is the output function the result would be : **154**

> 4 + 1 = 5 --> 25 --> 25 * 2 = 50 --> 50 * 3 = 150 --> 150 + 4 ==> 154

The code which i am currently using is :

```
(define (s n) (lambda (L) (buildfunc n L)))

(define (buildfunc n L)
  (cond
    ((null? L) '())
    ((equal? (car L) 0) (* n n))
    ((positive? (car L)) (+ n (car L)))
    ((negative? (car L)) (* n (car L)))
    (else
    (buildfunc n (cdr L)))))


(define C (s 3))

(C '(1 0 -2 -3 4))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Here's how I'd go about solving this:

```
(define (buildfunc cmds)
  (define (process cmd value)
    (cond ((zero? cmd) (* value value))
          ((positive? cmd) (+ value cmd))
          ((negative? cmd) (* value (- cmd)))))
  (lambda (n)
    (foldl process n cmds)))
```

Example usage:

```
> ((buildfunc '(1 0 -2 -3 4)) 4)
154
```

---

Update: you can certainly unroll the `foldl` into a manual loop, like so:

```
(define (buildfunc cmds)
  (define (process cmd value)
    (cond ((zero? cmd) (* value value))
          ((positive? cmd) (+ value cmd))
          ((negative? cmd) (* value (- cmd)))))
  (lambda (n)
    (let loop ((value n)
               (cmds cmds))
      (if (null? cmds)
          value
          (loop (process (car cmds) value) (cdr cmds))))))
```

Comment: Is there any way to write the function without using `foldl` ? I am new to scheme and trying to understand the way in which i can traverse through the list .